# Parse error on guards

Tags: haskell

```
factorial :: Int -> Int 

factorial 0 = 1

factorial n 
   | n < 0 == error "Cant call a nagative number"
   | otherwise = n * factorial (n-1)
```

Can anybody explain why I am getting this error?

```
haskell.hs:77:2: parse error on input ‘|’
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to use `=` not `==` in a function definition:

```
factorial :: Int -> Int 
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n 
   | n < 0     = error "Cant call a nagative number"
   | otherwise = n * factorial (n-1)
```

- `=` is a syntactic atom used for defining things;
- `==` is a function/operator used for comparing values.

Comment: So sorry for wasting your time,at least you get points for answering my question

Comment: well about 30 seconds of my life!

Comment: @Charana: I can see you haven't accepted almost any of the answers to your questions, including this one — you should change that habit!

Comment: wait,how do i do that,aren't i just supposed to up vote?

Comment: there is a checkbox by the side of all answers, which, when you click it, will turn green. you must have seen it... once you find it, it would be nice if you went back to your older questions and accepted the best answers, if they solved your issue.